# Function cannot access variables within another function

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math 

def main():
    radius = float(input('What is the radius?'))
    circle()
    print('the cirumference is', circum, '.')
    print('The area is', area, '.')


def circle():
    area = math.pi * radius ** 2
    circum = math.pi * radius * 2
    area = '{0:.3f}'.format(area)
    circum = '{0:.3f}'.format(circum)

main()
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm  trying to print variables from the other function but it won't work as intended.

Comment: How do you expect the function to access the other function's local variables?

Comment: I didn't consider that. How do I make it access the other variables? Set new ones for that function?

Comment: Have you learned about scope? Variables only exist in their scope, so in `circle`, the variables are discarded once the function finishes executing. That means you can't use them in `main` because they are out of its scope. You can A. return them and store them in `main`, B. use global variables that can be accessed throughout your whole program.

Comment: Ahh just saw this. Very helpful in understanding global actually. Obviously Im quite the amateur simply trying to pass a required class. My professor doesn't do much to teach us though either.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the variables you are trying to access have not been initialized. If you want to access variables and assign them values without passing them to the functions and methods, you must initialize them outside the scope of the function and explicitly say that they are `global` inside the function before you do anything with the variables. If you don't explicitly say that the variable is `global`, it will be treated as a local variable within the scope of the function being run and is inaccessible after the it is finishes.

```
import math 

radius = 0
circum = 0
area = 0

def main():
    global radius

    radius = float(input('What is the radius?'))

    circle()
    print ('the cirumference is', circum,'.')
    print ('The area is', area,'.')


def circle():
    global radius
    global circum

    area = math.pi*radius**2
    circum = math.pi*radius*2
    area = '{0:.3f}'.format(area)
    circum = '{0:.3f}'.format(circum)

main()
```

If you pass the radius as a argument to `circle(arg)`inside a function call, you can assign the return values variables inside the `main()` function and access them from there.

```
import math 

def circle(radius):

    area = math.pi*radius**2
    circum = math.pi*radius*2
    area = '{0:.3f}'.format(area)
    circum = '{0:.3f}'.format(circum)

    return area, circum

def main():

    radius = float(input('What is the radius?'))

    area, circum = circle(radius)
    print ('the cirumference is', circum,'.')
    print ('The area is', area,'.')


main()
```

Comment: OMG! that worked!! totally makes sense now, except for setting equal to 0. Can I ask what that does?

Comment: @JeremySparks that's initializing the variable. These are some *very* basic foundational skills you need to know before you even dive in.

Comment: @JeremySparks In order for it to know the variable exists, you must initialize the variable. Python abstracts its types so it could `None`, `0`, or an empty string, but it's usually best to initialize as the type of value you are expecting it to be. In your case, a numeric value such as `0` since those variables are meant to store the calculations for the area and circumference of a circle. This is necessary if you are trying to access a value that has not been declared yet.

Comment: Gee Andrew thanks! your feedback has taught me SOO much about python.

Comment: thank you zken! you're a shining example of how to properly post on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your are accessing the `radius` variable inside circle function, but it is not defined in the scope of circle function. So you will got an error when running this program.

Every variable's could only be seen in the scope which it was defined. As the `radius` variable is defined in `main` function, `radius` will only be seen in the scope of `main`.

If you need to share your variable between different function, you should defined the variables outside the functions, and declare them as `global` inside the function, then the program will know that you want to assess the variable from the global scope. `circum` and `area` are similar with `radius` variable.

So your code should look like this:

```
import math
radius, circum, area = 0, 0, 0

def main():
    global radius, circum, area
    radius = float(input('What is the radius?'))
    circle()
    print('the cirumference is', circum, '.')
    print('The area is', area, '.')


def circle():
    global radius, circum, area
    area = math.pi * radius ** 2
    circum = math.pi * radius * 2
    area = '{0:.3f}'.format(area)
    circum = '{0:.3f}'.format(circum)

main()
```